# What is the TickFrequency equivalent of slider in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, slider, silverlight-5.0

I am trying to create a `slider` using **`silverlight`** and i am under a situation that i have to  drag the slider with certain frequency and it is achieved in wpf using `TickFrequency`  but i couldnt find the alternative to do so using silverlight.

Suppose my slider is:

```
Slider slider = new Slider();
```

In explain what i want to do is:
  If i a slider whose max= 10 and min=1 and my slider frequncy=2 so what i want is
  when i drag the slider then it must drag by `0->2>4>6>8>10`  . Not like : `0->1>2>3>4>5>6>7>8>9>10`

Now ,could someone please help me ?

I tried this:

```
slider.LostMouseCapture += (o, e) =>
        {
            double distanceFromFactor = slider.Value % 2;
            if (distanceFromFactor > 1)
                distanceFromFactor = distanceFromFactor - step; //This step is decided dynamically rather 2/0.5/3 or whatever..
            slider.Value -= distanceFromFactor;
            txtblUnits.Text = Math.Round(slider.Value).ToString() + " units";
        };
```

But the problem is when it works fine when i have `slider.Max=4`, `slider.Min=-4` and `step=2` . But if i do `slider.Max=4`, `slider.Min=-4` and `max =0.5` it still updates the same result as in  the previous `txtblUnits` but this time was expecting the updates of slider drag like `-4->-3.5->3.....->4`.
How to make solution of this ?

Comment: You need to change the modulo operator to also use your `step` size rather than just be fixed ... `slider.Value % step`. Also the `distanceFromFactor` needs to use `step/2` rather than the fixed value of `1`, it is checking whether you need to round up or down. I'm sure there is more elegant maths for this, but you can take the example given and make it work for you. Assuming you understand what it is doing, and why.

Comment: but if i take step as 0.5 then will double able to read it as 0.5 or do i need to use decimal instead of double?

Comment: Updated answer to show where step is being used

Comment: use `var` and save yourself hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your slider will move right to the end just with one drag is that you are handling the `ValueChanged` event, and altering the value of the slider within it, which will raise a `ValueChanged` event, which alters the value of the slider, which raises a `ValueChanged` event ... repeat until bored.

Instead of that you could use the `LostMouseCapture` event to detect when the mouse has been released, and then quantise the value to your desired increments. Something like this:

```
private void MySlider_OnLostMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var step = 2;
            var halfStep = step/2;

            var distanceFromFactorOfStep = MySlider.Value % step;
            if (distanceFromFactorOfStep > halfStep)
                distanceFromFactorOfStep = distanceFromFactorOfStep - step;

            MySlider.Value -= distanceFromFactorOfStep;
        }
```

NOTE: this only changes `Value` when mouse is released, so you can't use a real-time binding to display the Value in, say, a `TextBox`: it will only have a factor-of-2 value after this method has run.

Also you should set `SmallChange` and `LargeChange` on your Slider to 2, so that your UI can cope with a user clicking or using cursor keys, and not just rely on them dragging.

EDIT: Logic explanation.

(1) To increase/decrease the value in steps you want to limit the `slider.Value` to be a multiple of your step size.
(2) Taking the modulo of the raw slider value gives you a 'distance' from the nearest, lowest, factor of your step size.

```
E.g. With a step size of 2 and a raw slider value of 2.532,
the modulo will be 0.532 (2.532%2 = 0.532). 
With a raw slider value of 13.152 the modulo will be 1.152.
```

(3) You could just take this modulo value and subtract it from your raw value to give you a new slider value that is a multiple of your step.

```
e.g. 
2.532 - 0.532 = 2.
13.152 - 1.152 = 12
```

(4) But this rounding down means that a raw slider value of 1.99999 (for example) will be converted to 0, rather than the closest multiple of step - which would be 2, for a step size of 2. So to see whether the raw value is closest to the lower multiple or the higher multiple you should compare the modulo to half of the step size.

(5) From the example above, 13.152 is closer to 14 than to 12. You can see this mathematically by comparing the modulo (1.152) to half of the step size (1). If it is larger than half of the step size then you want to use the higher multiple of step. If it is less than half the step size you want to use the lower.

(6) If modulo > halfstep then subtracting the step size from the modulo will give you a value suitable for subtracting from the raw slider value.

```
e.g.
1.152 - 2 = -0.848
13.152 - -0.848 = 14
```

Comment: Does silverligth supports OnLostMouseCapture  ?

Comment: You have intellisense in your VisualStudio right? So have a look for yourself. Hint: events have a lightning bolt icon. Bigger hint: I wouldn't have written that code if it didn't work. 'OnLostMouseCapture' is the name of my handler, not the event. You can work that small piece out yourself, surely. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.slider_events(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: it do not have but there is another alternative Mouseleave but it is very slow to update the changed data and even i hover mouse over it then also its data changes

Comment: MouseLeave is not the event you are looking for. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostmousecapture(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: it speed is very very less

Comment: slider.LostMouseCapture += (o, e) =>{
                        slider.Value = slider.Value + step;
                        txtblUnits.Text = Math.Round(slider.Value, 1).ToString();
                    }
                };  
                {

Comment: Why are you showing me that code? It won't do what you want - it just adds '2' (or your step) to whatever the current value of the slider is. So if I stopped the slider on a value of 13.1234 it would turn the value into 15.1234. The `TextBox` will then show something else entirely different. The code I provided  *actually* sets the value to the closest factor-of-2

Comment: 'it speed is very very less'. You have removed the `ValueChanged` event handling haven't you? There's no reason what I posted will be slow.

Comment: YES I HAVE REMOVED THE ValueChanged  AND KEPT LostMouseCapture  but speed is less

Comment: Speed is less than what? This is a single method that fires when you release the mouse - how is this slowdown exhibiting itself? What is slow? Show your code, if it isn't the exact same as the code I posted.

Comment: Please, try and *understand* the code before asking obvious questions. Yes, 2/2 is 1 ... which is the half-distance between your stepsize of 2. So if the raw value is less than that half-distance then round down to closest factor of 2, if it is above that half-distance then round up. You MUST try to understand what is going on, you can't just copy code people have given you and expect them to do your work.

Comment: thanks for the answzer it works but to be honest i do not understand your logic you used.(understanding it is aalso important). Why you have halved the step ? why you compare the modulo obtained (i mean distancefactor) in if condition "if(distanceFactor > halfStep)". Could you please explain it as well. would be great of you.

Comment: One more question (do not worry LAST). Can i limit the slider drag to a certain value ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this, Get your sliderValueChanged event to save the current and then add 2 to every change. or Use LargeChange and SmallChange Properties of the slider.

```
Slider slid = new Slider(); 
public MainPage() 
{ 
InitializeComponent(); 

slid.LargeChange = 2.0; 
slid.SmallChange = 0.0; 
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(slid); 
slid.ValueChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<double>(sldr_ValueChanged); 

} 
void sldr_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e) 
{ 

slid.Value = Math.Round(e.NewValue * 2) / 2; 
txtBox1.Text = slid.Value.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: OK let me implement it if it works . I will comeback to mark you  as answer

Comment: If i  use Large change and small change then also do i need to do ValueChanged += new eveernt ?

Comment: @user234839 then no need

Comment: @user234839 the code describes both ways, if you dont want, just remove the event

Comment: But sajeetharan int he second way you do not do somthing like  value= value+2;

Comment: @user234839 i have described there, it just you have to implement

Comment: please see the edit of question. I implemented your coede and it created 1 problem

Comment: @user234839 Obviously, it will move forward since you are adding 2 each time, you should find a mechanism to add and subract

Comment: buyt i couldnt understand how will i decrease the 2.

Comment: And what i dont understand is i just move the slider little and it go to the maximum end just by moving a little. I mean why slider go to Max values on alitle  move . When i debug the control stays in the "+= (o, e) =>" block until slider do not reach max value. Why it happnes. How to get a rid of it ?

Comment: And if i use first way simply doing slid.LargeChange = 2.0;
slid.SmallChange = 0.0; will not do any update since i am using the current position dragged in atextblock as you can see in my txtblUnits.Text of my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56538/discussion-between-user234839-and-sajeetharan).