# round of a big decimal value to small decimal value in c#

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, math, silverlight-5.0

I am working in c# and i do **not** want thing like this:

```
value = 1.658598554646 to value= 2
 or
value = 1.2256485526 to value =1
```

I want to do something like :

```
value = 1.658598554646 to value = 1.7 //see upto one intger after point(.)
value = 1.2256485526 to value = 1.2
```

How to do that in c# ? Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: you have to store value in decimal and set demial point

Comment: decimal DEBITAMT = Math.Round(1.658598554646, 1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one decimal you can use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round.aspx), and set the number of decimal points you round it to,

```
decimal value = 1.658598554646;
OneDec = Math.Round(value , 1);
```

Comment: not yet , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24486628/what-is-the-tickfrequency-equivalent-of-slider-in-silverlight/24507881#24507881

Comment: I hav tried somethign i can show you µ..But it is not the exact solution: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56538/discussion-between-user234839-and-sajeetharan

Answer (score 1):

How use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var result  = Math.Round(value, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
decimal DEBITAMT = Math.Round(1.658598554646, 1);
```